# Split String by logicals with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've the following string:

```
string text = "Hello && my || Name & is | Tom"
```

Now I want to split the string into different parts without the logical operators between the words. I've tried the following, but I get only one string with the whole text.

```
String[] result= Regex.Split(text, @"\&&\||\&\|");
```

Whats wrong?

The expected output is an array with 5 strings:

- Hello
- my
- Name
- is
- Tom

Comment: Why not use `s.Split(new[] { '|', '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`?

Comment: I thought that regex is more performant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No regex solution, just splitting:

```
String[] result = text.Split(new Char[] { '|', '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: It will also split on `&&` and not mere `&`

Comment: @Amit Joki: it will split *twice* on && and then *remove* the empty part.

Comment: Okay.. I got it. That's why remove entries option is there I suppose.

Comment: Maybe you also want to split on whitespace characters like `' '`, so the resulting strings have no leading spaces.

Comment: @sloth `String.Trim` would suffice for that.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to,

```
String[] result= Regex.Split(text, @"\s*[|&]+\s*");
```

This splits your input according to one or more `|` or `&` symbols. `\s*` matches zero or more spaces , and `[|&]+` matches one or more `|` or `&` symbols.

Comment: Thank you that works. One last question. If I also want to split the text according to a `"`. How can I do that?

Comment: just add `"` into the character class. `@"\s*[|&""]+\s*"`